# How to create new data frame/csv out file copying values from old one?

Tags: python, dataframe

I tried couple methods but none gave me exactly what I'm looking for.I added image to better show problem.
[image]

1. In old data frame I'm interesting in two colums "values" and "text".I would like to copy step by content of text cell based on value.
2. new data frame is empty has only columns names
3. as in image if value is 11 in old data frame copy text1 to Cat1 column in new data frames
4. I have to merge text in values in range 150-200 and following order in column text (text 7 part 3 starts in new line but it's part of the same informarion block.
5. move down in new postion in Cat1 in new data freame when find value 11 and start all steps above again

I tried to use:

```
df2['Cat1'] = df1.loc[df1['value'].between(10, 11), 'text'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

or first Equalize the lengh by filling new data frame with NaN

both methods assigned text to right category but following order(index) in old data frame, for example:

Cat 1 Cat 2 Cat 3
text1 NaN   NaN
NaN   text2 NaN

I'm looking for sugestions how I can get it? Give up data frames and just go trought text wit regex?

In advance Thank you for your time

Samples of code which I used and I tried to adapt to this taks

```
df2['one'] = df1.loc[df1['left'].between(24, 25), 'text'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

or

```
# Sample data for df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'left': [23, 24, 25, 124, 125, 126, 224, 225, 23, 24, 25, 124],
    'text': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1', 'f1', 'g1', 'h1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2']
})

# Create a placeholder list for each column of df2
one = df1.loc[df1['left'].between(24, 25), 'text'].tolist()
two = df1.loc[df1['left'].between(124, 125), 'text'].tolist()
three = df1.loc[df1['left'].between(224, 225), 'text'].tolist()

# Equalize the length of lists by filling with NaN
max_len = max(len(one), len(two), len(three))
one += [np.nan] * (max_len - len(one))
two += [np.nan] * (max_len - len(two))
three += [np.nan] * (max_len - len(three))

# Create df2 from these lists
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'one': one,
    'two': two,
    'three': three,
    # ... and initialize other columns as needed
})

# If you have more columns in df2, you can add them with:
for col in ["four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]:
    df2[col] = np.nan

print(df2)
```